# Why Is ServiceScope Causing Null Reference Exception?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In the following code, I define the `_serviceScope` variable in the constructor.  However, this results in a null reference exception when I call .SaveChanges() on my `dbContext`.

```
public class Seed
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private IServiceScope _serviceScope;

    public Seed(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        // define service scope in the constructor
        _serviceScope = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
    }

    public async Task EventTypes()
    {
        string[] eventTypes = { "Copy", "Counter-Proposal" };

        var dbContext = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        foreach (string eventType in eventTypes)
        {
            if (!dbContext.EventTypes.Any(x => x.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == eventType.ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                await dbContext.EventTypes.AddAsync(new EventType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = eventType });
                // null reference exception occurs on this line...
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task EventScheduleItemTypes()
    {
        string[] eventScheduleItemTypes = { "Orientation", "Event" };

        var dbContext = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        foreach (string eventScheduleItemType in eventScheduleItemTypes)
        {
            if (!dbContext.EventScheduleItemTypes.Any(x => x.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == eventScheduleItemType.ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                await dbContext.EventScheduleItemTypes.AddAsync(new EventScheduleItemType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = eventScheduleItemType });
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By contrast, when I define the variable inside the EventTypes method, the code runs without error.  **Why can't the `_serviceScope` be defined in the constructor and used throughout the class?**  Does it have to do with the way the IServiceScope gets disposed?

```
public class Seed
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Seed(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task EventTypes()
    {
        string[] eventTypes = { "Copy", "Counter-Proposal" };

        // define service scope in the method
        var _serviceScope = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
        var dbContext = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        foreach (string eventType in eventTypes)
        {
            if (!dbContext.EventTypes.Any(x => x.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == eventType.ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                await dbContext.EventTypes.AddAsync(new EventType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = eventType });
                // no errors
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task EventScheduleItemTypes()
    {
        string[] eventScheduleItemTypes = { "Orientation", "Event" };

        // define service scope in the method
        var _serviceScope = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
        var dbContext = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        foreach (string eventScheduleItemType in eventScheduleItemTypes)
        {
            if (!dbContext.EventScheduleItemTypes.Any(x => x.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == eventScheduleItemType.ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                await dbContext.EventScheduleItemTypes.AddAsync(new EventScheduleItemType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = eventScheduleItemType });
                // no errors
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, I use the class like so:

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    var Seed = new Seed(app.ApplicationServices);

    //await Seed.Roles();
    //await Seed.Users();
    await Seed.EventTypes();
    await Seed.EventScheduleItemTypes();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.CoreLoggerExtensions.SaveChangesFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, DbContext context, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at ProjectX.Seed.<EventScheduleItemTypes>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\VSO\Source\Internal\Project X\ProjectX\Startup.cs:line 174
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ProjectX.Startup.<Configure>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\VSO\Source\Internal\Project X\ProjectX\Startup.cs:line 87
```

**Edit:** It also works when I create the methods as static and pass each method a new scope. Apparently, it's getting rid of that scope and not telling anybody. Is there a better way of doing this so I don't need 4 scopes!?

```
    await Seed.Roles(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>());
    await Seed.Users(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>());
    await Seed.EventTypes(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());
    await Seed.EventScheduleItemTypes(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

*Note:* I have also tried wrapping the methods in a using statement but the service is apparently gone regardless.

Comment: Is `_serviceScope` initialized (i.e. not `null`) at the end of the constructor?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, it is initialized.  Furthermore, I can query the database using the dbContext; however, I simply cannot call .SaveChanges() without receiving the null reference exception as described above.

Comment: Any clues in the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I added the stack trace.  I notice the issue happens when I call a second function which also shares the serviceScope.  Neither the serviceScope nor the ApplicationDbContext service are resolved at the time the error occurs.  Should I simply create the scope outside of the class and pass the services in via the constructor to avoid this?

Comment: ``System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write`` sounds like you've wired up an invalid trace logger or something

Comment: @Neil I have not done any work regarding trace loggers in this application.  Something related to .NET Core, perhaps?

Comment: The NullReferenceException is coming from a bug in the framework. If you disable Just My Code in the debugger and go all the way to the top of the exception stack (look in the Events list in VS) you should see the real exception before it gets caught.

Comment: FWIW there's an issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9599 which is tracking at least the NullReferenceException

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem .Do not create the services in the constructor, this will basically make all services singletons.
Move them into your method .